# Can we find two measures $\nu$, $\mu$ which $\nu\ll\mu$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite while $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Can we find two measures $\nu$, $\mu$ which $\nu\ll\mu$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite while $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

I want to justify the Radon-Nikodym theorem but couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prescribe measure $\nu$ by $\nu(A)=0$ if $\mu(A)=0$ and $\nu(A)=+\infty$ otherwise.

This for instance where $\mu$ is the Lebesguemeasure on Borelsets in $\mathbb R$.

Then $\nu\ll\mu$, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite but $\nu$ is not.